# Transforming AVI video in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, directshow

I am doing a project in C#.Net. I wanted to read frames of AVI video, edit them, and then write them in a new AVI file (something like a transform filter)

I know a process in which I can create my own direct show transform filter, but that would be in C++ and I wanted to avoid it.

Is there anyway to accomplish this in .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [Splicer](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=splicer&title=News%20Feeds&referringTitle=Home) which was development specifically for creating or editing video files in .NET, and it is mostly completed. I believe one of the listed features is exactly what you want:

> *Modify individual video frames during encoding via standard C# mage Drawing code*

Comment: This one has a feature that I wanted to use.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/

**Edit:**

or http://sourceforge.net/projects/taoframework/

Comment: There aren't any public downloads. How is that gonna help the OP?

Comment: oops, I knew I looked this up recently, just looked at my notes rather than google. Have updated the post with what I had found before, its wraps/includes ffmpeg, which supports video.